# How to use pandas to modify rows in an Excel file by condition?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I got an excel file full with wrong arrangement, and I think it is possiable to speed up my correction by using python and pandas.

the proper content of the excel file may like this:

| Name | Gender | Age | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Male | 22 | A |
| Liu | Male | 19 | C |
| Kim | Female | 30 | B |

but now it is like this:

| Name | Gender | Age | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Male |  |  |
| 22 | A |  |  |
| Liu | Male |  |  |
| 19 | C |  |  |
| Kim | Female |  |  |
| 30 | B |  |  |

So far I've learn about the basic operation for pandas, is there any function in pandas to solve it?

I'm not much familiar with python, please let me know if I missed providing any other information.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, :2].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 4), columns=df.columns)
print(df)

# Output
  Name  Gender Age Group
0  Tom    Male  22     A
1  Liu    Male  19     C
2  Kim  Female  30     B
```

You can replace `df.iloc[:, :2]` with `df[['Name', 'Gender']]`